# My dog won't accept pork chops in 1.12.1 doggy talents mod

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I've been trying to feed my dog in minecraft 1.12.1, and it just won't accept food. This happens with any minecraft dog. I can tame a wolf but they just won't accept the pork chop. When I right click the dog just sits and wags it tail. Any help would be much appreciated. 
Many thanks
Sarah

Comment: Known bug: https://github.com/ProPercivalalb/DoggyTalents/issues/55

Answer (score -1):

khowing this is the doggy talents mod 
you should place down a bowl and get the dog to Touch the bowl 
that way the bowl will be set to that dog 
you can fill the bowl with food and the dog will automaticly get it when needed

if you mean breeding you need to give the dog a Breeding treat 
which are prizy to make